# How to lock the default keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

In my application I want to open the default keyboard when an activity starts and keep it opened until the activity is finished.

The reason for this behavior is that I need to add some text in this activity.
So, what should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
SearchActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm != null){
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

use this code in onCreate().

Comment: Ok Thanks. It works. But what should i have to do to make default Keyboard go away on the finishing of that activity or on any button click ???

Comment: It Work for with above code but now i want to go away with button click or on finishing of the activity.

Comment: imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS,0);  use this onFinished(0

Comment: ok. Its work on Button click event. But there is one problem. I got the keyboard on starting of the activity. but in this activity if i select back button of the device, it hide the keyboard and now if i finish the activity then it will show the keyboard on the previous activity where i have nothing to do with that keyboard.

Comment: for the purpose that you don't want to hide the keyboard on back button, you will have to create your own keyBoard, i think. and on previous Activity you can hide the keyboard by the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(txtBuscar.getId(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

ok you can try this in your mainfeast filr..

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

Comment: Ok I have test it. And instead of the txtBuscar i have inserted my own  edittext but its not working as i want. What else i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix

```
> InputMethodManager imm =
> (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
> imm.toggleSoftInput(txtBuscar.getId(),
> InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```